# Using MongoLab in Heroku doesnt work unless I provide CC number?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have developed a nodeJS application using Angular as the front-end (used MEAN stack and plan to use Bootstrap with it) and when I try to deploy it to Heroku, whenever I run this line: heroku addons:create mongolab I get the following output:

```
bruno@bruno-HP-epicsauce:~/herokuFinalApp$ heroku addons:create mongolab
 !    Please verify your account to install this add-on plan (please enter a credit card) For more information, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing Verify now at https://heroku.com/verify 
bruno@bruno-HP-epicsauce:~/herokuFinalApp$
```

And in both sites (mongolab and Heroku) it says it's free... I have already defined the heroku env variable called MONGOLAB_URI, like this:

```
bruno@bruno-HP-epicsauce:~/herokuFinalApp$ heroku config:set MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://USER:PASS@ds041643.mongolab.com:41643/dbNAME
Setting config vars and restarting rocky-sea-9859... done, v4
MONGOLAB_URI: mongodb://USER:PASS@ds041643.mongolab.com:41643/dbNAME
bruno@bruno-HP-epicsauce:~/herokuFinalApp$ heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URIMONGOLAB_URI: mongodb://USER:PASS@ds041643.mongolab.com:41643/dbNAME
bruno@bruno-HP-epicsauce:~/herokuFinalApp$
```

It still doesnt work...

In the git repository I have the following file structure:

[image]

The app is listening on the port: process.env.PORT instead of some local one and the package.json file contains the correct dependencies as it was automatically generated with npm init.

Inside the procfile I have the usual reference to the file that contains my server side code:

web: node server.js

The app.js contains the Angular client-side code.

Is there any 100% free way of deploying an app in Heroku with a DB hosted somewhere?

Comment: Even if the add-on you choose is free of cost, you will be required to verify for security purposes. [Source](https://kb.heroku.com/why-do-i-need-to-have-a-verified-account-for-a-free-addon-or-custom-domain)

Answer (score 7):

You have two options to use MongoLab services on Heroku:

1. Connect to existing MongoLab deployments from Heroku (no credit card required)
2. Add MongoLab as a Heroku add-on (credit card required)

Since you have set up MONGOLAB_URI, I assume you created a separate account with MongoLab and created a new MongoDB deployment. In this case you don't need an addon. If you have your MongoDB driver configured to use the connection URI, setting MONGOLAB_URI config on Heroku is usually enough.
More info on this [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#connecting-to-existing-mongolab-deployments-from-heroku)

Heroku asks for a credit card for verification purposes. It won't charge you unless you choose paid addons.

> You must verify your account if you want to:
>   Add any add-on to your app, even if the add-on is free. The only exceptions to this are the free plans for the Heroku Postgres and Heroku Connect add-ons, which can be added without verification ([source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#when-is-verification-required))

Answer (score 5):

A message from their staff:

> You won't be charged if you only use the free plan. Unfortunately some
>   people use free add-on plans for evil purposes so we need a way to
>   verify the account. Right now we do that by requesting a valid credit
>   card, and we may add more verification mechanisms in the future.

I'm in the same point than you, but as you can read, there is no problem to add that information (but to be honest I'd prefer another way as well).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know it will actually charge you, it just wants CC to verify.  But you could always just use http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/ or Digital Ocean VPS (which is not actually harder than setting up your dev machine as long as you aren't expecting perfect security etc.).

Comment: With Dokku as far as I've seen my computer will act as server?

Comment: Well actually Dokku runs on a VPS (like Digital Ocean/Linode/EC2) and uses Docker containers.  Digital Ocean may be the cheapest and easiest to set up if you google 'Digital Ocean dokku' or 'Digital Ocean MEAN'.  You would not need Mongolab if you didn't want it but the VPS are $5-$10 per month.  But maybe first put CC in check if they actually charge.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `mLab MongoDB` add-on, just manually add `Config Vars`